# in Onclick Event.. I have error

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

```
public void clickImage(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.a_01_b) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.a_02_b) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.a_03_b) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

I wrote in mainactivity.java like this..

and, in XML.. I wrote android:onClick="clickImage" in each ImageView.

But it makes error like this in first sentence I wrote here.

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
- Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
- void is an invalid type for the variable clickImage
```

.. What is this error? I have to do what..?
I think no error in codes..

Please give me solution..

P.S. I cleaned Project , but it's same.

Comment: do u want to keep the `onclick` in xml or can i give you a solution on activity?

Comment: would you show me your `xml` plesae

Comment: What does the row before the clickImage method look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note** that with the XML onClick, Android will look for the onClick method `clickImage()` only in the current Activity. This is important to remember if you are using fragments, since even if you add the XML  using a fragment, Android will not look for the `onClick` method in the .java file of the fragment used to add the XML.

So we need to know if you are using framents , or multi activity calling

#### Edit>

no error in you xml , it seems that there is an error in you java activity, and because I don't have your java , i will give you a solution independent of your xml

```
ImageView im;
im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.a_01_b);
im.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

in your xml remove this

```
android:onClick="clickImage"
```

#### Edit 2

at the top of your java class put this:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
```

at you code do this:

```
ImageView im;
im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.a_01_b);
im.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

instead of `YourActivityName` put the name of your activity

Comment: It's too long to write here.

Comment: I don't no other solutions to show you my XML, so I give you link.

Comment: it seems no error at xml, why don't you try to set the onclicklistener on java ? it is easy too

Comment: can you introduce cool site or other else that give me  solutions to setting onclicklistener on java and setting xml?

Comment: You have some error in your Java code. Show us some more of it and we might be able to help.

Comment: thanks for code.. and when i use that code in java, I have to write another thing in my xml?

Comment: No, I'm so sorry because you help me like this.. but I have some error too, and I don't know to solve problem either.. Here is link. http://wemakeucc.com/java_error.jpg

Comment: check my `edit 2` you have to import classes as i did, and instead of `YourActivityName` you have to put you real acitivity name

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax error in your mainactivity.java. Perhaps you put the clickImage method within another method. Or something else, it is impossible to tell exactly without seeing the full code.